# Is it possible to send a text message from firebase to a phone number?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, sms, twilio, flutter

I want my firebase to send a text message to my app (which is coded in flutter). Can the firebase send SMS using the server?

Answer (score 5):

You can use the Twilio third-party service in a Cloud Function.

Have a look at these docs:

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/using-sms-and-voice-services-via-twilio

https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/cloud-functions-twilio-sms (which shows how to integrate Twilio in a Cloud Function)

The Firebase Cloud Functions documentation is here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/

*Note that you will have to subscribe to a Blaze or Flame plan, because "the Spark plan allows outbound network requests only to Google-owned services".  Check https://firebase.google.com/pricing/ and hover over the question mark next to Cloud Functions for more details.*

Comment: Okay but for Twilio I will have to create a new app, is there a way i can use twilio with my existing app which is coded in Flutter

Comment: Yes, you should use it in a Cloud Function, which is executed on the back-end, on  a managed environment in Google/Firebase's cloud. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/