# Is there is any way to send message to mobile number using firebase and python?

Tags: python, firebase

I am completely new to firebase. I want to send message message using firebase and python to mobile number. I did not found any thing that helped me to solve my problem. Sorry if this question is too basic. If anyone could help me with my problem i would be very grateful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use twilio or any other services..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to send a text message from firebase to a phone number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51634914/is-it-possible-to-send-a-text-message-from-firebase-to-a-phone-number)